# Android : Google Cloud Messaging Error

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, google-play, google-cloud-messaging

I'm following a tutorial and I've pulled the google gms git repository.
I'm getting an error "cannot resolve symbol android" when I import

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
```

I have updated google play services. Here's my gradle -

```
...
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
}
```

Where am I going wrong??

Comment: Add base package also. Some of the classes require base package so I think it will resolve error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This code.** It's very simple and easy steps.

Link: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check the base package and make sure the gradle is updated